# Not able to test Async Retrofit2 API calls using MockRetrofit

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit2

I am trying to test a retrofit2 API using MockRetrofit. 
I have the following service API:

```
  interface AuthApi
  {
      public Call<Result> signin( String username, String pswd );
  }
```

The Mock implementation looks like this:

```
    public class MockAuthService implements AuthApi
    {
         BehaviorDelegate<AuthService> delegate;
         public MockAuthService( BehaviorDelegate<AuthService> d )
         {
             delegate = d;
         } 

         public Call<Result> signin( String username, String pswd )
         {
             return delegate.returningResponse( new Result() ).signin( usernam, pswd );

         }
    }
```

My test looks as follows:

```
@Test
public void testSuccessfulLogin()
{
    // Create MockRetrofit object

    MockAuthService service = new MockAuthService( mockRetrofit.create(AuthService.class) );
    Call<Result> call = service.signin("user", "pswd" );
    call.execute(); //This works fine. I get the result obj and check status code and stuff
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>()  // This does not work
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse( Call<Result> call, Response<SignInResult.Result> response )
        {
            System.out.println( "onResponse" ); // This is never called
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure( Call<Result> call, Throwable throwable )
        {
            System.out.println( "onFailure" ); // this is never called
        }
    } );
}
```

The async part (call.enqueue())of the unit test does not work. The callbacks (onResponse or onFailure) are never called. 
The sync calls work fine.
Any ideas why only the async calls are not working.

Comment: The problem was I was not waiting for the background thread to call the callback methods. Once I put a Thread.sleep(1000) after enqueue was called it started working correctly.

Comment: yeah, still same to my problem, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was not waiting for the background thread to call the callback methods. Once I put a Thread.sleep(1000) after enqueue was called it started working correctly.